# Can't switch AWS profile CLI but can do in the Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to run AWS CLI commands using a different profile:

```sh
.aws$ cat config 
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[profile secondaccount]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<SECOND_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/admin
source_profile = default
```

```sh
.aws$ cat credentials 
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ID
aws_secret_access_key = KEY
```

The `SECOND_ACCOUNT` has admin role (access to all resources) that has Trust Relationship to allow any users from `FIRST_ACCOUNT` to assume it.

```
"Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<FIRST_ACCOUNT>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

My account on the `FIRST_ACCOUNT` also has policy to assume role:

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
```

- I **can switch role using the console**.
- I have tried to attach policies directly to my username on the `FIRST_ACCOUNT` to have sts:assumeRole.
- I've tried to attach my user ARN from the `FIRST_ACCOUNT` to the Trust Relationship of the `admin` role of the `SECOND_ACCOUNT`.
- There's no explicit DENY attached to my username.
- I've tried adding the `admin` role of the `SECOND_ACCOUNT` to both my `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials`.

However, I can't switch to another profile using the CLI:

```sh
$ aws s3 ls --profile secondaccount

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied
```

I've tried what suggested [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html), and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I've found the solution from [an AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/).

The issue:

In the Trust Relationships of the `SECOND_ACCOUNT` `admin`, there's the condition:

```sh
"Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
```

that means it requires token from MFA to execute CLI commands.

So I did:

```sh
$ aws sts get-session-token --serial-number MFA_NUM --token-code CODE_FROM_MFA
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": ID,
        "SecretAccessKey": KEY,
        "SessionToken": TOKEN,
        "Expiration": "2019-07-12T01:14:07Z"
    }
}
```

Then I added to the `.aws/credentials`:

```sh
[mfa]
aws_access_key_id = ID_FROM_ABOVE
aws_secret_access_key = KEY_FROM_ABOVE
aws_session_token = TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE
```

Then edited the `.aws/config`:

```sh
[mfa]
output = json
region = us-east-1

[profile secondaccount]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<SECOND_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/admin
source_profile = mfa
```

Then I was able to run CLI commands with `--profile secondaccount`.

If you choose to do this way which is AWS best practice, AWS recommends that having a script to automate the process of getting new token.

If you're "lazy", remove the `condition` in the Trust Relationship.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `secondaccount` to assume the `admin` role, it must use the credentials from your `default` profile. In the provided example your `default` profile doesn't have access keys defined, hence it can't magically assume role in the `secondaccount`. For instance

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id=AKIAJQZVTAZXBSTXXXX
aws_secret_access=MYSECRERACCESS
output = json

[profile secondaccount]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<SECOND_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/admin
source_profile = default
```

It works for you in the console, because you're using username+password combination login before assuming target role, whereas for CLI you suppose to provide access key + secret key to do that

Comment: Thank you @b.b3rn4rd. I have the access key and secret in credentials. From AWS docs, it seems like I need to add the second account to the config file, not the credentials. I've also tried adding the role to both. I'll update my question.

Comment: I added the key id and secret to the config file (similar to your answer) and I still have the same error.

Comment: I've actually found the solution. I'll answer the question. 